# How do I set the system locale to English (India) rather than English on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: libreoffice, language-support, locale, 23.04

I want my system locale to be English (India) rather than English. I tried the kernel command line option `locale.LANGUAGE=en_IN.UTF-8` when booting. However, the Writer application in the LibreOffice suite still picks English (US) as the locale. I had tried the following at the command-line for Writer to pick English (India):

```
alias soffice=$( which soffice )\ --nologo\ \2\>\>\ ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/soffice_output.txt ; alias soffice ; LANG=en_IN.UTF-8 soffice &
```

Please refer to output of following command for details:

```
ramumsrk@ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-desktop-amd64:~/Desktop$ localectl
      Warning: Settings on kernel command line override system locale settings in /etc/locale.conf.
 Command Line: LANGUAGE=en_IN.UTF-8         
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
               LANGUAGE=en
               LC_NUMERIC=en_IN.UTF-8
               LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8
               LC_MONETARY=en_IN.UTF-8
               LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8
               LC_NAME=en_IN.UTF-8
               LC_ADDRESS=en_IN.UTF-8
               LC_TELEPHONE=en_IN.UTF-8
               LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN.UTF-8
               LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_IN.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: (unset)                      
   X11 Layout: us,in
    X11 Model: pc105
  X11 Variant: ,eng
  X11 Options: grp_led:scroll
```

How can I set the system locale to English (India) rather than English on Ubuntu 23.04?

Comment: I posted an answer. Out of curiosity I wonder why you wanted to set `LANG` to `en_IN`. Considering that the locale categories which make a difference from a region POV are `en_IN`, what is it you would like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The Language options have been reduced to the ones where there are translations available. In your case, since there are no English (India) translations, it simply defaults to en_US.UTF-8.

Examples of other English locales which can be set are en_GB.UTF-8 and en_CA.UTF.8, since translations into British and Canadian English exist.

You may want to go to *Settings -> Region & Language* to understand the background for this setup. It wouldn't have made much sense to provide 15-20 different English language options in that GUI, would it?